# create folder structure based on file

Tags: svn, sh

Currently, I'm trying to improve my svn merge process. To achieve this, I started creating a shell script that looks up which folders are changed since the last dropmerge. The output file of that script looks like this:

```
/components/intmodules/
/components/ext/modules/EmailConn Runtime/
/components/emailconn/
/components/ftpconn/
/components/
/redist/
```

Now I want this folder structure to be created on the file system, using svn updates. All folders should be checked out with `--depth files`, except for the deepest (non-components), those should be checked out with `--depth infinity`.

How would I achieve this. How can I iterate over the folders and checkout/update these folders, including those with spaces in the name?

Comment: How can we know which ones should get `infinity`? Other than that, a simple `while read dir` loop should be all it takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to merge into a working copy that is not depth infinite, so this might not be a good idea in general.

That said, there is a sample script in the Subversion repository for checking out a mixed depth working copy based on an input file that describes what you want.  I would suggest you use this script  to do the checkout and adjust your script to produce the file format that the script wants.  It is pretty similar to what you show above so should not be too hard.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/svn-viewspec.py

Comment: Thanks @Mark, that works just fine! I can use this script to generate a viewspec file, and get the checkout exactly the way I want.

echo "Format: 1" > viewspec.txt
echo "Url: $url" >> viewspec.txt
echo "" >> viewspec.txt
awk '{if ($0 == "/components/") {print "."$0"~"} if ($0 != "/components/") {print "."$0"**"}}' output-all.log >> viewspec.txt
echo "./~" >> viewspec.txt